# Test if method is being call on alien class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stub

How can I test if `MyModel.all` is called ?

The following code doesn't work as I expect it:

```
class MyClass
  def call
    cached_records
  end

  private

  def cached_records
    Rails.cache.fetch(self.class.name.underscore) do
      MyModel.all
    end
  end 
end
```

```
RSpec.describe MyClass do
  subject { MyClass.new }

  describe '#call' do
    it 'only queries the database the first time' do
      expect(MyModel).to receive(:all).once

      MyClass.call
      MyClass.call
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate *"doesn't work as I expect"*? What do you expect? What is the current output?

Comment: Why do you expect `MyModel` to receive `:all` twice wheb you **explicitly cache** the returned value? It would obviously receive it once.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. The problem lies in the fact that despite me expecting `MyModel.all` to be called, it isn't. It seems that the `MyModel` I call within the spec is a different one than the one within the class.

Comment: Once again: it is called. But it is called once. Hence the test fails.

Comment: I fixed my code @AlekseiMatiushkin. I expect it to be called once indeed, but it's called none.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I found the answer by tweaking the expectation.

`expect(MyModel).to receive(:all).once.and_call_original`

Why do I need to specify to call the original method ?